# Android SelectableItemBackground not working

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

XML Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="48dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingEnd="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingStart="16dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp" />


<RobotoTextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:typeface="roboto_medium"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"/>
```

This is the layout for my rows in a recyclerview, I have used "?attr/selectableItemBackground" before and it worked great, but nothing is making this ripple effect work! Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: could you make your question a little clearer?

Comment: Sure, ill re-structure my question, essentially, im trying to get my recyclerview rows (shown above) to have the ripple effect/selectableItemBackground effect. I added it to the background of the linear layout but its not showing when i click on a row. I have other projects exactly like this where it works, but for some reason this layout wont work

Comment: At what api level it is not working? Both on Lollipop and pre-Lollipop?

Comment: Correct, it won't work on lollipop or KitKat.

Answer (score 14):

Turns out, the selectableItemBackground was working all along, it was hidden with a combination of a white backgrounnd and the ThemeOverlay.AppCompat, i put the Light theme to each row and the ripple was then visible.